# How to connect to Mongo DB which is in remote server to my Docker?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Hi I have an application where I am using docker-compose. I have large amount of data in the remote mongo DB server which is running on port 28107. How can I connect from my docker-compose to this remote server?

Below is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    # container_name: myapp
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '52000:52000'
      # - '8080:8080'
    #   - '4300:4300'
    #   - '4301:4301'
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://test:test@ip_address:28107/test
    # command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mongo:28107", "--", "npm", "start"]
    links:
      - redis
      - mongo
  mongo:
    # container_name: myapp-mongo
    image: 'mongo:latest'
    ports:
      - '28107:28107'
      # - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      # - ~/Downloads/db_dump_09_01_2020:/data/db
      - /data/db
      # - /data/configdb
    # command: mongod --auth
  redis:
    # container_name: myapp-redis
    restart: always
    image: 'redis:4.0.11'
    # command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
    depends_on:
      - helper
    sysctls:
      - net.core.somaxconn=511
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
  helper:
    image: alpine
    command: sh -c "echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled"
    privileged: true
```

In the above code, in the environment parameter, I have mentioned the remote mongo DB server url. I have all the data in that url. I don't want to export that data in my localhost and mount it in my docker container but instead, I would like to directly link my docker container to that remote mongo DB server.

How can I do it ? I am new to the docker concepts.

Comment: It seems like you have configured everything right from the docker side. Maybe there is a problem with the remote mongo server? What kind of error do you get? Can you connect to your remote server from the host where you running docker?

Comment: I logged in to my docker container and executed the command: docker exec -it <container_name> bash
After logging in the container, I executed the command: mongo ip_address:28107/test, I got the following output:

__**MongoDB server version: 4.0.4
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
        http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
        http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
>**__

Comment: Hm, so everything is ok with connection. So, what kind of error you get when your app tries to connect using mongo url passed from the environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to connect to an external MongoDb server on a network different from your docker network. Then you shouldn't need.

> mongo:
> # container_name: myapp-mongo
> image: 'mongo:latest'
> ports:
> - '28107:28107'
> # - '27017:27017'
> volumes:
> # - ~/Downloads/db_dump_09_01_2020:/data/db
> - /data/db
> # - /data/configdb
> # command: mongod --auth

You should only need to provide the necessary environment settings of the remote MongoDb server to myapp.